# Expiring Fragment Cache without Sweeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I have a view that show point totals for the users with the most points.  I want to be able to expire the fragment cached view (using Memcached and Rails 3.2) every 15 minutes.

I could put it in a a sweeper that updates every time a new point record is created, but that will happen too often and will not reduce the load I'm putting on my servers for doing the calculations for the view.

I've also thought about using a scheduled job since I already use the [Whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever), but my understanding is that Whenever runs tasks based on rake tasks or models usually.  When I put `expire_fragment("leaders")` in a model method or rake task, I get an error.

Can someone please recommend an approach for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment(key)
```

Should do the job